# jquery compare two checked items from a list

Tags: jquery

I have a list of check-box items with number values like "30%", "20%", and I want to allow the user to check only two boxes and compare them and show the positive or negative difference value. I have started with the following code:

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="box" name="metrics1" value="" />
    <label for="metrics1">10%</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="box" name="metrics1" value="" />
    <label for="metrics1">20%</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="box" name="metrics1" value="" />
    <label for="metrics1">40%</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="box" name="metrics1" value="" />
    <label for="metrics1">60%</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="box" name="metrics1" value="" />
    <label for="metrics1">80%</label>

<div id="resultsection"></div>
```

JS:

```
 $('input[type="checkbox"]').live('click', function() {
     var selected = '';
     $('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(index, value) {
         if (this.checked) {
             selected += ($('label[for="'+this.name+'"]').html() + ', ');
         }
     });
     if (selected.length > 0) {
         selected = "You have selected the following: <br /> " + selected.substring(0,selected.length-2) + '.<br />';
     } else {
         selected = 'No metrics selected.';
     }
     
     $('#resultsection').html(selected);
 });
```

what this does is show the values of the selected items inside the #resultsection. What I need is get only two values and store them as two cookie variables to make use of them after page reload. Then we can add a button to compare between the two values like (first-value - second-value = %result).

I appreciate you help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done the logic for you ([**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bygqK/5/)). It does:

1. Disable input boxes after 2 selections
2. Stores the selected 2 values in an array and compares them for true and false.

Now you just need to store the values in cookies and do whatever you want to do with 2 values.

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').live('click', function() {
    var selected = '';
    var values = [];

    $('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(index, value) {
        if (this.checked) {
            selected += "<span>" + $(this).next().html() + " </span> ";
            values.push($(this).next().html()); 
        }

          if($('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length > 1 ) { 
             $('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(index, value) {
                if (!this.checked) {
                   $(this).attr("disabled", true);
                }
            });
        }
    });

    if(values[0] == values[1]) {
       console.log('true');
    } else {
        console.log('false'); 
    }

    if (selected.length > 0) {
        selected = "You have selected the following: <br /> " + selected + '.<br />';
    } else {
        selected = 'No metrics selected.';
    }

    $('#resultsection').html(selected);
});​


<input type="checkbox" class="box" name="metrics1" value="" />
    <label for="metrics1">10%</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="box" name="metrics1" value="" />
    <label for="metrics1">20%</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="box" name="metrics1" value="" />
    <label for="metrics1">40%</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="box" name="metrics1" value="" />
    <label for="metrics1">60%</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="box" name="metrics1" value="" />
    <label for="metrics1">10%</label>
<div id="resultsection"></div>​
```

Comment: thank you so much.. I tried your code and it is working, but when I unchecked a value to select another value other boxes are disabled. Is it possible to enable other boxes if I unchecked the second checkbox. Thanks

Comment: Thanks.. now I'm trying to update both values and return the cookies:
http://jsfiddle.net/bygqK/9/
this doesn't seem to work.. any help?